# How to update codeigniter view dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a third party API. When the user is on a third party app and does some activity like messaging, the third party will send me a JSON request of activity to my CodeIgniter app endpoint.

I want to update the view of CodeIgniter with a notification that user sent some message etc.

I need some light that how to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax (Core or JQuery AJAX).. I prefer JQuery AJAX

```js
// You can use a setInterval also, but im using button click to call api
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var url1 = BASE_URL+"controller/method"; // Or your API
     $.ajax({
      url: url1,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(response){
           // Access the json objects like this
           // eg. response.status, response.data etc.
           
           // Do DOM manipulation
           // eg. $('#target').text(response.data) 
      },
      failure : function(response){
       alert("Error! Please Contact technical support");
      }
     });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But event happens on third party app? How I update it on my codeigniter app in real time.